# Meaning of "Hadn’t Mrs. Pritchard almost said as much before she had caught herself"

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> I paid no attention to these stories until one afternoon she said, “I once saw your parents in Nairobi at a Government House garden party. I can’t be
>   sure, but I do believe you were with them. One doesn’t forget ginger hair, although I don’t recall you as being so thin. Of course I never for a moment
>   believed the tales of your father being disowned and sent away by your grandfather. That was just malicious talk, I am sure.”
>
> I didn’t believe it was malicious talk. **Hadn’t Mrs. Pritchard almost said as much before she had caught herself**? What did that mean? Was the grandfather truly looking forward to my visiting, or was I being forced on
>   him, the first step in the Pritchards’ desire to return to England? Would my coming truly make him better, or would this reminder of a son he had had to
>   send away cause him more misery?

Can we write it like this:had Mrs.Prichard said all of the story that Miss Limplinger had said to be not caught by someone else?

I really get confused by its meaning...

Source:Listening for Lions by
Gloria Whelan

Answer (score 3):

Not quite.

*Said as much* is an idiom meaning *said roughly the same thing*. It doesn't actually have the idea of the amount they said.

*She caught herself* means "She stopped, and didn't do something".

So, together, it means

> Hadn't Mrs Pritchard nearly said the same thing, but she stopped and didn't say it?

Comment: Thank you,  sorry but again it is unclear to me .You did not include "before" in your sentence as main sentence, and why you include "but"? . and Dose "she" refer to Mrs Pritchard? Sorry my English is not so good and would be very thankful for your help.

Comment: Yes. Mrs Pritchard had been going to say nearly the same thing, but before she said it, she stopped herself, and didn't say it.